# Multiple Imputation in R: mice vs. mi package

Tags: r

what are the advantages and disadvantages of these two packages for multiple imputation?

Here is my motivation for asking this question: I have used the `mi` package so far but I am unable to get convergence. My dataset is about 10,231x28. Four variables have 18-20% missing values, one has 14% and the rest is around 5% (or below). No convergence even after running on a server for 18 hours. Now I am wondering whether `mice` might work better.

Comment: Is it not converging or is it just taking along, long time?

Comment: After 18 hours, it displays the message `Time out, mi did not converge ( Sun Oct 21 16:59:57 2012 )`. There is an argument `max.minutes` to the `mi` function which allows you to set the max run time. I set this to 1080 (the default is 20) and received the message above at the end. Note that I still get my imputed datasets but it's not reassuring.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~yajima/Publication/mipaper.rev04.pdf)?  MI is a sophisticated statistical procedure with a complicated estimation procedure.  Changing a package is unlikely to solve your problems.  Let the difficult work begin! :-) .  If you need help on diagnostics, I recommend editing your question to reflect the new focus, then flag it for moderator attention as "Please migrate to CrossValidated."

Comment: Yes, I am using that paper. At the end, they write "One caution with the current incarnation is that mi may take some time to converge with big datasets with a high rate of missingness across many variables. We are currently investigating approaches to increase the computational efficiency of the algorithm". That statement motivated my question: Has `mi` improved and is `mice` better suited for these situations? I framed it more generally because I thought new users might be interested in the adv./disadv. of each package. But I will look into the diagnostics and might edit my question.